# Simulate mouse click on windows start up using scripts

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm looking for to find a way to write a .bat to simulate mouse right click on desktop, right after log on.
OS is Windows 8.1

Comment: Just because the command line is black with white text doesn't mean it is DOS.  Also, there's nothing built-in that would do something like this. Not sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish, but you'll probably have to write something using the Win32 APIs.

Comment: If I were you, I'd look into using something like AutoHotKey. You could then run a specialized AHK script from a batch file.

Comment: this can be done but you should try to path it with batch first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible within batch unless you create a batch file to then generate something like a VBS script and then run that VBS script, slight over kill though.

I'd use VBscript (.vbs) and add that to the startup folder to load when a user logs on to the machine.

```
Set WshShell = wscript.createobject("Wscript.Shell") 
WshShell.SendKeys("+{F10}")
```

Something as simple as the above .vbs script will perform a right click when ran. - Possibly the simplest way I can think of using a script.

Note: this right clicks where the mouse is pointing so perhaps a small wait command before the  click might be needed, or even [moving the windows pointer](http://en.allexperts.com/q/VB-Script-2351/2009/5/Set-Cursor-Position.htm) before the `sendKeys` command.

If you have multiple users then perhaps using a batch file would work well, you can store the vbs script on a network share that everyone can access and then you wouldn't have to modify the vbs for every user should you need to make changes.

See the below example.bat:

```
@echo off
start \\PATH\script.vbs
exit
```